# Content add subview not working?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uitableview, uiswitch

How is your day , Hope every thing went well

My question is that I have uiswitch in uitableviewcell . However when i used contentview to add the switch as a subview in the cell it does not appear on my cells ? Any one please do you Know why they don't appear on each custom cell ? THANKS IN ADVANCE .

Here is my code :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    UISwitch *switchController = nil ;

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

      switchController=  [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        switchController.tag=100;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:switchController];
        CGRect switchFrame = switchController.frame;
        switchFrame.origin.x = 50.0f;
        switchFrame.origin.y = 10.0f;
        switchController.frame = switchFrame;
        [switchController addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    }

    else
    {
        switchController =(UISwitch *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];

    }

//This for persist switch state when scroll up or down 
    if ([[[self.SwitchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]isEqualToString:@"ON"])
    {

        switchController.on=YES;

    }
    else
    {
        switchController.on=NO;
    }

   NSString *value = [[mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = value;
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0];

    return cell;

}
```

Here is the code of SwitchChanged :

```
-(void)switchChanged:(UISwitch *)sender
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
    NSIndexPath *index=[mainTableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    if (sender.on)
    {

        [[self.SwitchArray objectAtIndex:index.section] replaceObjectAtIndex:index.row withObject:@"ON"];

    }
    else
    {
        //Update my switch states array 
        [[self.SwitchArray objectAtIndex:index.section] replaceObjectAtIndex:index.row withObject:@"OFF"];

   }

    [padFactoids setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:SwitchArray] forKey:@"savedArray"];
    [padFactoids synchronize];

}
```

Comment: why u r adding to contentView of cell add it to cell..

Comment: Add the switch to the storyboard cell.. see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments i came to know you are using the storyboard fro creating table view. Add switch to the table view prototype cell and give tag as 100.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
 UISwitch *switchController =(UISwitch *)[cell viewWithTag:100];

 [switchController addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

//This for persist switch state when scroll up or down 
if ([[[self.SwitchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]isEqualToString:@"ON"])
{

    switchController.on=YES;

}
else
{
    switchController.on=NO;
}

 NSString *value = [[mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = value;
cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0];

return cell;


}
```

Comment: YES i did like this but still no appearance . Thank you for your time

Comment: Only switch is not appearing?

Comment: Are you using custom class for the cell?

Answer (score 0):

The fist thing is, that you have a frame with width and height 0 for that switch. Secondly, if you are using storyboards with prototype cells, it might not enter at all in that `if (cell == nil)`. Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

It would be easier to add the switch in the storyboard to the prototype cell, but if you want it programmatically, you can move the code outside the if and add a condition like:

```
UISwitch *switchController = (UISwitch *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
if (!switchController) {
      switchController=  [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
      switchController.tag=100;
      [cell.contentView addSubview:switchController];
      CGRect switchFrame = switchController.frame;
      switchFrame.origin.x = 50.0f;
      switchFrame.origin.y = 10.0f;
      switchController.frame = switchFrame;
      [switchController addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}
```

And of course, don't forget to set the width and height.

Comment: Thank you for your response . YES your are right i am using storyboards with my cell . So how can this be solve , i need to enter this clause if ( cell == nil ) because i have reusable cell with switch in each ? please help you will be a life saver @Levi

Answer (score 0):

Your switchController width and height is 0. You init the switch first with CGRectZero, after that you change the origin coordinates but the width and height is still 0.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. I did change the width and height of my switch but still not appeare

Answer (score 0):

Well i found your problem, try like this it'l work.
 Here problem is that after adding switch you are giving the title to the cell label it means label hides your switch.

`Problem`: cell.textLabel hides the switch.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

        UISwitch *switchController = nil ;

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                          reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

        NSString *value = [[mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = value;
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0];
          switchController=  [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
            switchController.tag=100;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:switchController];
            CGRect switchFrame = switchController.frame;
            switchFrame.origin.x = 50.0f;
            switchFrame.origin.y = 10.0f;
            switchController.frame = switchFrame;
            [switchController addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

        }

        else
        {
            switchController =(UISwitch *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];

        }

    //This for persist switch state when scroll up or down 
        if ([[[self.SwitchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]isEqualToString:@"ON"])
        {

            switchController.on=YES;

        }
        else
        {
            switchController.on=NO;
        }



        return cell;

    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. However the problem still there

Comment: still you are facing same problem?

Comment: YES could you help please ?

Comment: if you put above code as it is then it'l come because i checked with this code.